# Loading resourcebundle from non default location in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, resourcebundle

Is there any mechanism to load the properties file from the file system in `struts2`? I am coming up with a hot deployment mechanism. If I update the war file, it would be redeployed. I am able to reload properties file on the fly using

```
LocalizedTextUtil.clearDefaultResourceBundles();
LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("struts/resources");
```

but it would only look in the `struts2` default location.

Any solution, hack, workaround is heartily welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution

first in struts.properties struts.custom.i18n.resources=globalMessages
then, add the below code to the your StartupServlet or some other place that will execute where the server start

```
    URL[] urls;
    try {
        File file = new File("/your path");
        URL url = file.toURI().toURL();          
        urls = new URL[]{url};

        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        LocalizedTextUtil.setDelegatedClassLoader(cl);
        LocalizedTextUtil.addDefaultResourceBundle("globalMessages");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by:
1. Tell struts to use a certain property bundle.
2. Add it to the classpath

Example:

In *Struts.properties*:

```
....
struts.custom.i18n.resources=globalMessages
....
```

Create `globalMessages.properties` (and any locale specific bundles, such as `globalMessages_ru_RU.properties` ), place the bundle(s) in a folder called `/app_conf/i18n` and finally place the directory `/app_conf/i18n` in the class path.